# ImageView doesn't update

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to update a image from a imageview, debugging it I saw that is passing by all the code, but the image doesn't update.
Here is my code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);


ImageView view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.head);
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to me like you have 2 images.

Comment: Where are you calling this code? There's no context given as to where this code exists

Comment: try once using view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.head);

Comment: the first image is set directly on xml, using android:src="@drawable/leftarm"

Comment: @dymmeh I'm calling it on onDraw, my class extends View and implements onDraw, thats why I using inflater.

Comment: @Abhishek It doesn't worked to

Comment: v is not attached to any ViewGroup as you pass null in inflate method so it doesnt appear anywhere

Comment: @pskink how can I do that?

Comment: dont setImageResource in onDraw method, do it when you want to change the ImageView and dont use LayoutInflatet as you have your ImageView already in  the view hierarchy

Comment: A custom view is like any other Android view.  You declare it in layout XML and inflate the XML with setContentView() or whatever method you prefer, or add it to the root view in code.  The only thing your onDraw() should concern itself with is, err, drawing the view!

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `view.invalidate()`. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call `postInvalidate()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to call `imageView.refreshDrawableState()` after applying all parameters