# ImageView not changing with setImageResource()?

Tags: android

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

  ImageView button;



 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
}
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    }
}
```

Apparently if I put the `button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);`in the onCreate it works and changes images but not in the onClick? I tried debugging it and it ran the onClick code but didn't change the button image. I'm probably making a very stupid mistake but I can't figure it out.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.larry.app.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us your xml please

Comment: i dont think its the xml

Comment: I redo your code in an example and  It works fine (setImageResource works  ). Don't you have other things that you have added ?

Comment: i actually dont think theres anything else that would affect it. the weird thing is that  button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause); works in onCreate() but not onClick() even though onClick() is being called, i am certain of that

Comment: possible this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525587/imageview-doesnt-update/71216858#71216858

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use

```
android:src
```

to set the initial image in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

you had better set ImageView self OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code and tell me the result then :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

      ImageView button;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

        }
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    }
```

and in the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.larry.app.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i changed the project code to match this one, i thought the problem mightve been that android:src in the xml is permanent but that didnt fix it.

Comment: Aha i see ! I tested  both code (yours and mine) work in my simple example.
Check your project and based to answer try to find a solution. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClick there is a switch statement, and when I put the `button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);` before the switch it doesn't always activate even when OnClick activates. When I click one button android.os.SystemClock.sleep is executed which prevents the image from swapping. When the other button is pressed the clock doesn't sleep, so the image can switch successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same problem Larry faced when using the `setImageResource` method when changing the source of an *imageView*. For me this happened when trying to use a switch but for a different scenario. Incase someone would find it helpful, i'll explain how I used a work around for this from the code.

**SCENARIO**

For me, I had a *recyclerView* in one activity and based on the selection, it would start another activity using an *intent* and the widgets in the new activity will be manipulated by the click of the recycler view including an *imageView*

**SOLUTION**

Using an *If* or a *Switch* inside the new class did not work (Which was the problem). What I did was inside the Custom Adapter for my recycler view, I used an If condition (Again a Switch will not work) as follows,

**THE CLASS OF THE ACTIVITY WITH THE RECYCLER VIEW**

`@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
holder.indexTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
holder.nameTextView.setText(String.valueOf(name.get(position)));
holder.gradeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(grade.get(position)));

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, DisplayingProductDetails.class);

        if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(1))
            i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_1);
        else if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(2))
            i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_2);
        else if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(3))
            i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_3);
        else if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(4))
            i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_4);

        activity.startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    });
}`
```

The Important Part here is passing the Resource ID as a String from the `putExtra` method.

```
if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(1))
    i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_1);
else if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(2))
    i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_2);
else if(novaGroup.get(position).equals(3))
    i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_3);
else
    i.putExtra("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP", R.drawable.nova_grade_4);
```

**FROM THE CLASS OF THE NEW ACTIVITY**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaying_product_details);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    novaGroupImage = findViewById(R.id.novaGroupImage);

    novaGroup = extras.getInt("PRODUCT_NOVA_GROUP");
    novaGroupImage.setImageResource(novaGroup);

}
```

The important part here being using the resource ID inside the `onCreate` Method,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
novaGroupImage = findViewById(R.id.novaGroupImage);
```